Using "iff" in documentation
Is the term "iff" (as an abbreviation in "If and only if") commonly understood, when used in software documentation?  I thought so, but recently a colleague had not heard about it so I am wondering if I should avoid this term or if I could assume that the general programmer knows it.
Example:

This function returns True iff the value of foo is larger than bar.

I decided to ask here instead of at english.stackexchange.com, because the target audience are programmers.

I have nothing against abbreviations, but in this case it is quite easy to miss the double f. I don't think it is practical, and I wouldn't recommend it.

I this day and age, my first thought would be that it's a typo.

@MetalMikester the first word in your comment shows why your thought is right on spot :-)

@Hans-MartinMosner haha Indeed. I'm on no sleep.

Assuming your function always returns a boolean, you should simplify to "The function returns whether the value of foo is larger than bar.".

I have been a professional mathematician for decades, and I prefer writing/reading “if and only if” to “iff”. Shorter doesn't always mean better.

@GregMartin What's the history of that? I'd wager a guess that it was devised in time when things were handwritten or typed on a mechanical typewriter. It does seem like it would be tedious to write out.

I've never seen that abbreviation used before now (and I've been developing for decades)... like others, I'd assume it was just a typo if I saw it in documentation, which actually means it ends up looking unprofessional to anyone who doesn't recognise it.

I wonder whether this is a generational thing. The "iff" notation has been around for at least 70 years, but maybe it is less popular than it used to be. I found a 1955 textbook on General Topology by John L. Kelley in which he attributes the "iff" notation to Paul R. Halmos. I'm pretty sure I learned "iff" in programming classes in the 1970s and/or 1980s.

Take inspiration from good documentation written by others. For example, in the Python docs it's common to phrase this like "True if the queue is empty, False otherwise" (example).

Modern IDEs can spellcheck your comments. ”iff” is not in the default dictionary so unless you get everyone to add it, you get red wriggles. Time has passed on from writing math by shorthand, just use the full term.

As a non-native speaker, it took me years to realise "iff" isn’t a typo.

Wow, I did not expect such a lively discussion! That lead me to search for iff in the most borderline large Python project I know between math and programming, SciPy. One of the few iff examples there is an insert(), but even there the usage is "A tuple is returned iff the input argument tck is a tuple, otherwise a BSpline object is constructed and returned." Which pretty much renders the purpose of an iff pointless.

As a philosopher, I know of "iff", but I was always wondering why such a typo-like looking word is used, why not "iaoi" or something like that. In German, the abbreviation "gdw" is used, which stands for "genau dann, wenn", and literally means "if and only if".

What would be the difference with just writing "This function returns True if the value of foo is larger than bar"? To me, that means the exact same thing. I don't really understand why you'd even need "iff" there.

Just because it is common in math, does not mean it is common among software engineers or whatever audience your documentation is intended for

Incidentally, your typical programming language may allow you to write this as if foo > bar return True ; else return False;and not as iff foo > bar ... :)

Just as an example of why you should write both sides of it out like @kaya3 suggests: As currently written, it would be perfectly valid for this function to throw an exception if foo is equal to bar.  Since the behavior in that case isn't specified, everything up to (and including) a kernel panic is still technically correct behavior.

@HagenvonEitzen It's worth noting that the syntax of programming makes iff redundant anyway. It's application is in pure logic where if A then B doesn't imply if not A then not B. But in a programming context (here presumably Python), if A: B inherently means if A is not true, don't do B. As such, I can't think of a scenario where an iff statement would add any utility as if statements already implicitly act as iff. (Not to mention in this specific case, a hypothetical expression return True iff foo > bar else False can be trivially expressed as return foo > bar.)

I learned iff in documentation from my excellent first-year Comp Sci prof. Since then I use it everywhere myself. I've never had anyone else understand it the first time. I should probably stop, and will do so iff someone tells me to...

@Dnomyar96 The difference is that if doesn't exclude other mechanisms by which True might be returned. iff means not only P > Q, but also -P > -Q. More relevant for mathematical rigour in the definition of the function's behaviour than for clarity in everyday programming, where if is generally assumed (all things being equal) to mean iff.

It only works until some junior developer decides to correct the spelling in all the comments.

@Abion47 Unless of course you write if (condition) { thing(); } else { thing(); }. But this fact of what it means "in programming" is not very relevant; you can always defeat in implementation what you claim happens in documentation.

@LukeSawczak The addition of else B doesn't change the semantics of what if A: B does. It just creates a larger logical expression with behavior that differs from that of its individual components.

@Abion47 What I mean is that nothing about the control keyword if excludes that some other cause might lead to the same consequent, which makes it parallel to the mathematical word if, not to the mathematical word iff.

@LukeSawczak Like I've said, the difference between the programmatic if and the mathematical if is that if A then B doesn't come with the implicit corollary if not A then not B - B can still be "true" even if A is not. But in programming, if A: B does come with the corollary that if A is not true, B will not happen. As such, for the purposes of the question being asked, programmatic if has much more in common with the mathematical iff.

@Abion47 ...unless B happens for another reason... as with the mathematical if.

@LukeSawczak You are interpreting B as if it was some function getting called, but it's not. B is the block of code attached to the if, and if the expression A is false, the block B will not be entered. Anything that actually happens in B and the possibility of it also happening elsewhere is irrelevant to that fact.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As you noticed, your colleague wasn't familiar with the term, so you can't assume that everybody (or even every software developer) knows it.
I would probably avoid using the term, mostly for two reasons:

this one (not everyone may be familiar, and documentation language should be quickly understandable)
it has a slightly elitist smell to it (this is probably just my personal perception, as I only encountered it in academic contexts)

Using precise language is a good thing, but some verbosity doesn't hurt :-)

Reason #3: it looks like a typo. Seriously.

FWIW I do suspect your reason #2 is just your personal perception, and is not widely shared enough to make it an important reason to avoid using "iff". It's no more elitist than math itself is elitist.

@DocBrown I recall reading some anecdote where the author had asked their significant other to review a paper they wrote, and the SO said something like "it all looked good except for some minor typos." And, you guessed it, they had 'fixed' all the 'iff' typos.

Reason #4: iff is assumed for documentation. "The function returns True if foo is larger than bar" → everyone assumes it returns False in any other conditions.

Reason #5, I see no functional difference between "if and only if" and just "only if". The former is the kind of fluff I would expect in a college paper of someone trying to meet a word count.

@DavidZ In the context of programming, I'd assume people who have a university education would know what iff means and people without wouldn't. That makes it pretentious.

@JackAidley And now do a survey of a hundred people about what they think what you wrote means, and consider whether this is the way you should be writing documentation :)

@JackAidley But they weren't claiming that. Read the comment again. He wasn't saying "if" and "if and only if" are the same, he was saying that "only if" and "if and only if" are the same. And now consider that you missed something this big, and yet would you think that "iff" is a good shorthand for "if and only if"? :D It might have been reasonable in handwritten text, but it certainly isn't when typing on a computer.

@JackAidley So why not explain how his comment is wrong, rather than explaining how an imaginary comment is wrong?

@Alpha I'd say that is a reason for writing "iff". People unfamiliar with it may assume it's a typo but they will still get the correct meaning. On the other hand, sometimes there is reason to think "if" might be used in a non-exclusive sense, and then the people who do understand what "iff" means are spared the need to dig deeper to find out (or to leave worrying that their exclusiveness-assuming code might break down at some point).

@Logarr The difference is that "A only if B" means that B is required if A is true, and we're presumably verifying that. e.g. "The user may access this resource only if they've already logged in" does not imply that every logged in user will access that resource (whereas iff would imply that). "If and only if" means something precise and distinct from both "if" and "only if". You're right that it looks a bit verbose, though. That's why we abbreviate it to iff.

@JollyJoker: Not even that - the "if and only if" is for a specific class of logic  classes at university, and...you'd have to take enough of those courses for it to be common enough things to make the distinction between "if" and "if and only if", meaning you would need to excel at that specific course. Instead, it comes across as something I might need a reference guide for; if I need to read documentation to understand how to read your documentation, you're doing documentation wrong - and I'm more than likely just not going to read your documentation.

@DavidZ: Or to summarize what I mentioned to JollyJoker, 'iff' comes across as pretentious and elitist because it's like writing a RegEx into your documentation to be read in the RegEx pattern format of your specific engine; that's the type of thing someone would likely need a reference guide for, and...why should they do that for documentation?

This comment section isn't the place to get into a back-and-forth about whether this expression is elitist.

@Logarr Huh, "Only if" is a unidirectional implication, while "if and only if" is bidirectional.

@Alpha Iff you assume fully defined functions, "iff" is reasonable to stipulate.

If your colleague doesn't understand it, take it as a learning opportunity. The idea is not to dumb down things to the lowest common denominator, but to lift everyone up.
Please note that there is a middle ground between "dumbing down" and "being a smartass", So if you are asked about it you just say "that's the abbreviation for if and only if". No word about how everyone should know this.

I regret that I have but one upvote to give. I was very surprised to discover that apparently a lot of the programmers here have never heard of "iff" given how useful and common it is. But I agree wholeheartedly with your second point: it's not their fault when no one taught them something before, and the solution is to teach them now.

No way. === If your colleague doesn't understand it, take it as a learning opportunity.  === If your colleague programmer doesn't understand it, then you can download believe the common read doesn't. till you're writing for. === Well it may be legitimate to explain logical functions to your reader, it's very unnecessary in this case.

@Miss_Understands "you can download believe the common read doesn't. till you're writing for" - what? I can't parse your comment.

@Bergi Ahh, hell! I use speech recognition and if you don't check it carefully, that stuff happens. When I say downvote, it always types download. When I said comma, It typed comments. === What pisses me off more is that I can't go back and correct it. But if it's not perfect, that means there's errors in it. === oh well. === Anyway, thank you for pointing out that I have to reread my stuff more carefully.

There are times when I want to read documentation to understand a piece of code, and there are times when I want to learn useful (but inessential) new words. The overlap between these is virtually zero.

@Sneftel I'd say the whole point of documentation is to learn things, which includes not only code but also ways to talk about code. Of course what you don't want is anything that unnecessarily distracts from the information that you're actually searching for, but the nice thing about "iff" is that it has low distraction and confusion potential for those who don't understand it. Meanwhile, for those who do understand it it's a time saver because it makes the statement unambiguous without introducing boilerplate that would make the documentation unwieldier to read than it needs to be.

"which includes not only code but also ways to talk about code"... no. If I am reading documentation about a particular piece of code, I only want to learn about that particular piece of code. If I want you to give me an inessential vocabulary lesson, I will ask you for one.

@virolino Nope, that’s not correct.

Use iff iff the domain is appropriate.
From a dictionary:

iff
(mathematics, logic) Short for if and only if.
A rectangle is a square iff all four of its sides have the same length.

Assuming English text, iff you are writing a text in the domain of mathematics and logic, you may use iff.
That means you should not use the word if you are not writing a text in the domain of mathematics and logic.
This does not cover unrelated meanings in other languages.

The term iff for if-and-only-if may be understood in computer science and logic, and also bears an implied symmetry ("and not when not").
It is a useful operational term, with quite expressive power. But it needs always explanation, and the more or less implied exclusion of the negative case (when that is the case) needs also to be explained.
For example, using a foot note with a clear wording could be a solution.

This function returns True iff1 the value of foo is larger than bar.
1 ) if-and-only-iff = necessary and sufficient condition. And not so when bar less or equal to foo.


Footnote is a good solution - it explains the term close to its occurrence and does not hamper the reading flow for those who are already familiar with the word.

Except you won't write a foot note in a source code. And I'm not sure if any doc generator supports it, I've never seen it.

@freakish: it is unclear whether the OP meant "documentation in source code" or "separate documentation". Maybe they have literate programming in mind - which uses TeX for creating the docs, which is surely capable of adding footnotes ;-). But don't get me wrong, I agree that footnotes are impractical for source code docs.

Thanks in general. Documentation in code has only the room of a popup for a method's javadoc or such. Probably senseless.

@DocBrown corrected two most evidint typos, though the text still should be formulated differently here and there. Thanks.

@DocBrown much obliged; my (non native) English is normally better, so my earnest thanks.

@freakish At least the ReST underlying Sphinx generated documentation supports footnotes.

I would avoid using "iff" in documentation for a pragmatic reason: it's entirely too easy to double-tap the 'f' key, turning "if" into "iff", completely changing the meaning of what you wrote.  It's a lot harder to accidentally type "if and only if" when you meant to type "if".
(I would consider using it iff the programming language in question has it as a keyword.)

Are there programming languages that have iff as a keyword?  How would it be different from if in source code?

Documentation should be unambiguous, obvious, and appropriately convey importance to the reader. It's important to know your audience; perhaps your readers are thoroughly digesting the documentation, but in most cases the majority of documentation is skimmed rather than read, and it's easy to misread "iff" as just "if". "if and only if" is a significant statement and "iff" does not do well to convey the weight of the statement to the reader. Also, "iff" strikes me as a notational symbol rather than something you would expect in plain language documentation.

It is easy to misread, but also if you misread it as "if" then you will probably still get the correct meaning from it.

Mathematical formalism is for the code; documentation should communicate clearly and precisely. In the given example, think about what you intend with the extra 'f'. The implication is: when foo isn't larger than bar, the function won't return True. Okay, but documentation is primarily about what the code will do, not about what it won't do.
Generally, if a function is returning a boolean, the natural assumption is that both True and False return values are possible, and that False is returned whenever True isn't. One doesn't expect, for example, the function to raise exceptions unless those cases are explicitly called out. So if that's what you mean, then say it. Common styles may range from:

Returns: foo > bar


This function returns a boolean indicating whether foo is greater than bar.

Any of these will be more concise than explaining what "iff" means.
On the other hand, if the function does something else in the other cases, you should say that, instead. Simply leaving it at "it doesn't return True in those cases" will lead the reader to guess, probably wrongly.

I have two points.

The double 'f' syntax is not common in all programming languages.  C# and Java are widely used examples of languages that do not use 'iff'.  While 'iff' was taught in several mathematics courses required for my CS degree, those courses may not be required for programming degrees or certificates, and your fellow programmers may not have been exposed to the syntax.

Fully understand what your documentation is doing here:



This function returns True iff the value of foo is larger than bar.

This implies the value of false being the default state prior to the evaluation, and/or the return of false when foo is not larger than bar.  Your documentation on this matter should be EXPLICIT.  You should both avoid the shorthand, and explicitly include your Else condition.
Here is why I say point 2:
If the documentation is for an end user, e.g. API documentation, they should not have to guess if the returned state is True or False or NULL or guess if the Default state prior to evaluation is NULL or False.
Many readers will have read this and assumed "It's common sense that if something is not true, then it is false."  And if you pause a moment longer, you will think of instances where you worked with application code where this is not the case."
If the documentation is for a developer to use in writing the code itself, you need to properly set the expectation of what you want to receive. Implied execution does not convey the entirety of your expectation, and is a great way to get back something that does not meet it.

Unless I've misunderstood your first point, I don't think it applies - this question seems entirely unrelated to whether any programming language actually uses iff. (And in fact I'm not familiar with any programming language that uses it, though that shouldn't matter.)

OP is under the assumption it is a common phrase developers would be exposed to.  I'm pointing out that a lot of young developers may not have been exposed to it because it is not used, and therefore not taught, in high level language development.

@Kevin Few if any languages have the words "tree", "pointer", or "database" in their syntax, but I would still expect a programmer to know what they mean if they appear in the comments. iff describes a property of the algorithm, but isn't a step in it, so it's unlikely to appear in a statement or expression (except perhaps in declarative logic languages like Prolog), but that sort of high-level guarantee is exactly what comments are for.

You are making the same assumption as the OP.  Developers are taught, and expected to know, the constructs of trees and pointers, they may not have been taught IFF and instead only know it as IF ELSE.  I even provided an example of how IFF is taught in various maths courses, but was not covered in any programming study.

@Ray you are very likely to see the words "tree", "pointer" or "database" (or their abbreviations) in a source code that interacts with those objects. Not only in comments, but in the actual code, as part of variable/function/class name. So I have no idea what you are talking about.

@freakish I'm talking about "The double 'f' syntax is not common in all programming languages" (emphasis added).


This function returns True iff the value of foo is larger than bar.

Do you actually mean this function returns (the result of the expression) foo > bar?  it's not immediately clear: perhaps  the function sometime does not return, or sometimes returns a value that is neither true nor false.
My take is leave the language of mathematical logic on the shelf, and use the langauge your audience, the programmer, will be most familiar with. Mixing languages leads to confusion. For exampls do "functions" in the programming language satisfy the mathematical definition of a function?

In your example, the problem is not the use of "iff", but the fact that there are no additional requirements about what-if-not-iff ... So if one extreme is bad, the other extreme is not inherently good either. Just to clarify: "This function returns True if-and-only-if the value of foo is larger than bar." is equally bad from the point-of-view of "perhaps the function sometime does not return, or sometimes returns a value that is neither true nor false".

So "This function returns True iff the value of foo is larger than bar, if it returns at all, and if it returns a Boolean value" ;-)

I'm guessing OP thought iff was saving words. in some languages there are more than two boolean values

Many others here have stated that "iff" looks like a typo, yet none of them has suggested this approach: Make it so that it does not look like a typo.

This function returns True iff the value of foo is larger than bar.

This function returns `True` <i>iff</i> the value of `foo` is larger than `bar`.

(Note that *this syntax* renders as <em> (emphasis) rather than <i> (idiomatic text). Use that iff <i> is not a choice.)
Italicizing a word does not magically make the reader understand it, however, so an explanation of some kind is still necessary.

How does that make it clear it’s not a typo? One might also use emphasis if the case is notable but not exclusive.

@MisterMiyagi Two things: First, <i> does not mean emphasis; second, I never said italicizing make it clear that "iff" is not a typo (only less so). I also noted that an explanation is still necessary.

Well then how does that make it so that it does not look like a typo?

Maybe it depends on IDE, or keyboard but then wouldn't it be easier to just type "if and only if"?

@MisterMiyagi If something looks different from the rest, it is intuitively understood as having received extra attention and would thus less likely to be an error. This might work for one person but not another; if you don't feel that way, fair enough.

@Piro This answer is about how to make "iff" look less like a typo. I'm not saying that it's better than just writing the phrase out in full (it isn't), just that this is another approach to consider.

I think any good documentation should explain the concepts it uses:

Explain (or provide a reference for) formal syntax notation being used
Explain the meaning of symbols being used
Explain abbreviations and acronyms being used
Explain any keywords that may not be universally understood (like "iff", but you could also think of "implies")

Also I think the use of "iff" is justified to use (but see above) if the documentation is very formal (rather rare these days); still it could be spelled out ("if, and only if").

Where do you stop that?

Depend on the audience of the documentation, naturally. And it's a matter of taste. Actually I found an example in ECMA-367: "5.7 Validity: “if and only if” rules"

There are already several good answers (thank you all for contributing), but there is some detail I did not yet see anywhere.
Any documentation is not written for the experts (except for occasional reference), but for the people which have (and ideally they want too) to learn. So using "iff" should be more than appropriate.
However, there is a small catch - no one can learn anything if that anything is cryptic and not explained.
So what I would do is something like this:

Explain "iff" at the beginning of the document in the "Definitions and abbreviations" section, specifying at least one reliable source (e.g., a dictionary).
Spell "iff" with capital letters as IFF for a triple purpose: a) to make it obvious that the spelling is not a mistake, b) to draw the attention that there are 2 F's there actually - which carries a lot of important information and c) to make it obvious that, etymologically, the word is actually an abbreviation.

Without the clarifications above, anyone can infer or assume anything, which beats the purpose of writing the said documentation.
You are of course welcome to find other ways to transfer knowledge to the readers of your document, if you do not fully agree with my way.

"IFF" looks like an initialism to me, not the short form actually meant.

@MisterMiyagi: There are exceptions to the rule, indeed. But since there is no definitive non-modifiable list of all initialisms, we can create initialisms of our own, if there is no risk of ambiguity. So if the documentation is not about file formats on Amiga, and is not about military / combat / competition stuff, then IFF can stand for iff. Or you can find another way, as I already wrote in the answer.

" Or you can find another way, as I already wrote in the answer." I am still looking for one that works in isolation without presupposing the knowledge that iff is a "word". Even the variations with defining it on first use / glossary requires people to actually read those first. Perhaps linking to a glossary would do?

@MisterMiyagi: and what is the difference between "link" and "specifying at least one reliable source (e.g., a dictionary)" ?

The difference is where the link is. This answer suggests to have the link only in the "Definitions and abbreviations" section, requiring the reader to read the section first. I was wondering (admittedly not very clearly) whether every use of "iff" should be a link, making every use work on its own and in any reading order.

@MisterMiyagi: And what happens when the document is printed on paper? Or when the Internet is not available, for any of the many reasons? The section "Definition and abbreviations" became a standard in the technical documents, as well as the section "Referenced documents", for very good reasons. Trying to reinvent a successfully used wheel might not always lead to better results. And if a John Doe cannot even use a "Definition and abbreviations", then if, iff and IFF become irrelevant entirely - the root problem lies elsewhere.

@MisterMiyagi: Additionally, for a CHM-style help documentation, making iff a link makes total sense. Or at least adding a tooltip to each iff (if it is possible to add tooltips to non-link text).

A link to the glossary (if you want to call that "Definition and abbreviations", be my guest). This would still work offline, and even printed would indicate it is a term that can be looked up (bonus points if the print version preserves  the link, e.g. as a footnote or similar). The root problem is that John Doe has little reason to consult the glossary for a seemingly mistyped "if”, which seems to require some marker at the site of use to fix.

If "iff" absolutely must be used and cannot be replaced by the more usual English terms, then using capitals, bold, italics, or some other form of emphasis feels a good idea for a term which is so easily taken to be a typo. It makes it a little clearer that this is a deliberate usage, particularly after the second or third instance, and it hints to the user that they can look in the definitions section. It should definitely be defined, either on first use with a pointer from the index, or in a definitions section, as it's not a safe assumption that every reader will have encountered the term.

@DawoodibnKareem: Fixed, thank you.

SURPRISE! Most readers aren't as educated as you are. It's the smart man's burden. And it can be shocking.
Think about it. The ONLY place anyone could ever encounter the term IFF is in a class on formal logic. It's just not part of the general vocabulary. Your fellow programmer didn't even understand it.
Smart people make the same mistake that stupid people do, which is why I call it The Universal Human Mistake: assuming that everyone else has the same knowledge and intent and motivation as you do.
I make the same mistake myself. It's universal. I assume everybody tells the truth when they say something, and that they want to know the truth when they ask me a question. But I once had a boss who was a compulsive liar. He explained that some people in the organization were "our enemies" and he always assumed everyone else was scheming and lying.
In fact, that's when I came up With the idea Of The Universal Human Mistake.

"The ONLY place anyone could ever encounter the term IFF is in a class on formal logic." That's not true. It is quite common in every branch of math. And the second half of the answer isn't related to the question at all.

@freakish Sure, the term may be in a user manual. But without having been exposed to it in a class or in a book, the reader is unlikely to understand it. It's not a factual issue; it's a writing style issue.

The vast majority of mathematics is not formal logic, and most mathematicians do not study formal logic. When I studied mathematics, formal logic wasn't taught until an optional third-year module which probably less than 25% of the cohort opted in for (lectures were on Saturdays at 9AM!). But the word "iff" would have been used in practically every module all the way through the whole course, starting on the first day. It may seem like a minor distinction, but it's the basis for your answer, so it matters that it's not literally true. And hyperbole doesn't go down well here.

The distinction I refer to is the one between "mathematics" and "formal logic", as the purpose of my comment was to point that distinction out. I apologise if that was unclear, but I also don't think my consistent use of the past tense was unclear enough to suggest that I am still a student. Also it's a bit weird to suggest that I might not have encountered the word "iff" in a course which I said used that word consistently all the way through. Anyway, your primary claim, "The ONLY place anyone could ever encounter the term IFF is in a class on formal logic", is objectively wrong.

The very rare times I want to use if-and-only-if in a computer program comment, I use the 3-character sequence <=> (or if that jumps out as an operator, <==>). It's a real logic symbol, which officially means the same thing as IFF (Wikipedia logical equivalence), but it more obviously indicates "I'm using a logic symbol". Briefly, if-and-only-if means a=>b and b=>a which is shortened to a<=>b and they both mean "both true or both false".
But I mean "very rare". Possibly very, very rare. For one thing, consider OP's "returns true if foo greater than bar". We wouldn't want to use iff or <=>, even if everyone knew it, since it's implied. If there were other ways to return true, we would have listed them. Saying things that are implied is confusing. Put another way, this is like adding "otherwise returns false".
For another, we rarely want to know IF vs. IFF. Say we're about to write a comment "restarts if idle for more than 20 seconds", but realize if-and-only-if is more accurate and write that. We've now told readers that there's currently no other way of restarting. We've let someone working on restart() know they can safely assume 20 seconds of inactivity. I don't think that's useful.
The few times I actually use <=> is explaining my logic. As a fake example "NOTE: amazingly, edges*2>=vertexes <=> maze can be solved!". I'm telling myself two things: checking for enough edges is a quick way to know the maze is usable; and checking for not enough edges is a quick way to know the maze isn't.

While the 3-character "spaceship operator" sequence  "<=>" looks similar to "⇔", it's heavily overridden in computing contexts. It means "three way comparison" in several programming languages, or "null-safe equality check" in SQL dialects. Math markup in prose is generally an anti-pattern, as symbol sequences are typically opaque to the non-cognoscenti: so "iff" is trivially searchable, but "⇔" is not. Overall, I'd consider "iff" far more likely to be unambiguous and colloquially known to those reading an English computer manual, but I'd recommend "if and only if" for most cases.

A reader could think I meant to suggest the single-character double-arrow symbol. I can fix that. Thanks.

But the spaceship operator doesn't ever mean iff in computing contexts, so far as I can tell. It means "3-way comparison", or "null-safe comparison"; a comparator, not a conditional operator. Your line "It's a real logic symbol, which officially means the same thing as IFF" does not appear to be correct, or at least, your link does not seem to support the claim you're making that it's ever used or understood to mean "IFF" by anyone other than yourself.

@DewiMorgan Ah! You think I'm one of those naive folks who "helpfully" propose a solution they just made up! You think I hastily misread a Wikipedia article. No. I learned <=> in the same computer logic class I learned IFF, and have seen it since used interchangeably. I assure you that if you make truth tables, IFF and <=> work out to be identical.

I can see this working out very badly in things like Javadoc comments, which are (approximately) HTML.

@DawoodibnKareem You don't think my last paragraph addresses this? Javadoc is for user-facing comments, while I felt my example of a rare time I'd use an IFF (which I prefer to write as <=>) was clearly an "internal" developer comment, explaining how something works. But if you're not seeing that I can try to clear it up.

No, I don't think your last paragraph deals with this at all.  The consumers of Javadoc comments are other developers.  So if you want to explain something to other developers, it's appropriate to use a Javadoc comment.  The exception would be if you're producing an API for use outside your company, and you want to keep some aspects of the implementation secret.  I would never dream of using the <=> in any kind of internal documentation; or the abbreviation iff for that matter.

@DawoodibnKareem I don't use Java so had to look it up. The first thing I found on was on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607641/javadoc-comments-vs-block-comments. You can downvote the top answer and leave a comment (it says to use normal comments for anyone maintaining the class and javadoc to explain the public-facing part).

If and only if means something. Use it when that’s what you mean.
This is the age of google. It’s not that hard to look something up. So don't feel like you have to explain what it is. Explain why you need it.
However, don’t use this because you want to show off. Use it when it’s important.
I’d rather you made me think than made me guess.
As for the abbreviation, "iff", like all abbreviations it's considered wise to spell it out on first use. Like you did when you asked this question.

While it's true that it's not hard to look something up, when reading I don't want to spend my time looking stuff up on Google. In this specific case, seeing "iff" I'd be more inclined to think it's a typo.

@MetalMikester better now?

@MetalMikester In that case you would ask and you would learn something.

@MetalMikester Meanwhile, all the other readers would think it's a typo. And then later in the text, they become very confused.. That's not good writing. Write for your audience.

FWIW, I tried looking"iff" up for fun and it took me quite a while to realise my input had been automatically changed to "if". After correcting it, google brought up a flower shop and research institute. Then I gave up.

@MisterMiyagi I used a different searching technique with a much more successful outcome. I went to the Internet Archive and searched for "iff" and "if and only if" in the text contents of documents with media type "text."

@MisterMiyagi The meaning was given in the OP.

@MisterMiyagi I can’t tell if you’re arguing in support of the answer or that it needs an improvement. The problem with a bare iff is the same problem with byob. If you never define it then all people can do is guess.

@candied_orange I removed the arguing since it was a tangent to comments, not the answer. I’m not in support of this answer because it’s main message, that it’s not hard to look something up and thus doesn’t need explaining, doesn’t apply to the expression under discussion - the bare "iff". If you want to improve it, changing the suggested method (spelling "iff" out once to make it searchable via the expanded term) to something that doesn’t require a specific reading order would be good.
